# Howto describe GUI independent of implementation technology?

Tags: generics, user-interface

I would like to describe the GUI and it's interactions on domain logic level independant from the implementation technology.

Are there some existing frameworks which would support this task and help me to translate my abstract GUI describtion into SWT, Javascript, something else?

Do someone know how the GWT Framework solves this problem?

Maybe some useful patterns for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question, but i thought embedded HTML+CSS might be a solution, since it's widely used by browsers, and it's very solid.
These is a c++ library called "librocket", here is the description:

> libRocket is the C++ user interface middleware package based on the
>   HTML and CSS standards. It is designed as a complete solution for any
>   project's interface needs.